# Visual Studio 2010 Properties Window

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2010, properties

I want to look at (a label name for example in) the properties box (shown by clicking the element in the interface window) and scroll through my code until I find what I'm looking for. The problem is that as soon as I click the code window, properties goes blank.

**Is it possible to change this behavior?**

- It's annoying to copy and paste or (*gasp*) remember what I was just looking at.

Comment: The way the Properties window behaves just doesn't have anything to do with how many monitors you have.  No. Use the [uservoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) to ask for feature requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the properties window is context-sensitive, so it shows properties for whatever it is you're looking at - in your case, code. now it just happens that code has no properties to show, which is why its blank.

I wouldn't want to change it - next thing you know, you'd be clicking on something and not seeing the properties for it! That would be bad.